# Recover from The Great Suspender extension's tabs being unusable

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

The Great Suspender was removed from the Google Chrome Store after it was discovered that the new maintainer was injecting an opaque blob of likely malicious code into the extension: https://github.com/greatsuspender/thegreatsuspender/issues/1263

My company profile maintainers disabled the extension, causing all my suspended tabs to be unusable. How do I recover the tabs?

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the existing version and install the [unhacked version](https://github.com/aciidic/thegreatsuspender-notrack) or a previously known good version ([May 2020](https://github.com/greatsuspender/thegreatsuspender/releases/tag/v7.1.6) should be fine).
2. Install Session Buddy from the [Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko).
3. Backup your Session Buddy history
4. Open the backup, and copy the "kkiipaehjlabinaapaffegihaigleijg" extension ID from "chrome-extension://kkiipaehjlabinaapaffegihaigleijg/suspended.html" tabs that are not able to load
5. Write down the new extension ID for the freshly-installed version. It will appear under "ID" in the description for The Great Suspender in chrome://extensions.
6. Replace all occurrences of that extension ID with the new extension ID for the new Great Suspender in the Session Buddy backup file
7. Remove the Session Buddy extension (to clear the history)
8. Install Session Buddy again and import the backup file
9. Restore the tabs.
10. They should now be able to open, since the URL matches the current extension ID.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by Jesse Spears, but another option (especially if you don't want to install any more extensions) is to just get `uri` part from extension URL like `extension://klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg/suspended.html#ttl=%D0%92%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20(186)%20-%20airelain%40gmail.com%20-%20Gmail&pos=0&uri=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox` and just use that instead. I tried to automate this process with a script, that you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66071974/74167